# Isolating triggers from WPF THemes

Tags: wpf, triggers, themes

HI,

I am using the WPF themes libary which is relaesed in Codeplex.com. All works fine. The theme used is applied. But there is a problem when I need to create a style for a button control(With triggers especially) and associate it with a button. What happens is the theme does not get applied to that button alone because I have a different style applied to it.

How do I take care of this?

-Ranjith

Answer (score 0):

This problem was "beaten to death" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096/how-to-apply-multiple-styles-in-wpf).