# How to apply multy style to single control in wpf?

Tags: wpf, styles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply multiple styles in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096/how-to-apply-multiple-styles-in-wpf)

```
<Window.Resources>   
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="style_1">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="style_2">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>    
</Window.Resources>


    <Button x:Name="btn_1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="153,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" Style="{StaticResource style_1}" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Button x:Name="btn_2" Content="Button" Height="40" Margin="281,95,262,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource style_2}"/>
```

Now i want to apply style_1 and style_2 to **btn_1** what should i do for that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply two styles to a single control in XAML.

What you could do, is letting style_2 inherit from style_1 by specifying

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="style_2" BasedOn="{StaticResource style_1}"> 
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

and then use only style_2.